# Erro na biblioteca facebook. "Malformed access token"

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

Estou tentando obter as informações de contato do usuário do facebook. Para isso estou utilizando o Facebook PHP SDK.

Consigo gerar a url de login corretamente. Porém, quando vou tentar obter as informações me é gerado o erro "Malformed access token".

O código que estou tentando atualmente é:

```
$code = Input::get('code'); // Código que vem na queryString

Session::put('facebook', Input::all());

$facebook = $this->facebook_api_instance();

// Aqui é onde eu passo o código OAuth2 e é gerado um erro
$request = $facebook->request('GET', '/me/friends', [], $code);

$response = $facebook->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
```

Comment: Você tem que gerar um Token e colocar na URL no código. Tipo assim:  `&access_token=$authToken`. Essa variável `$authToken` é de algo parecido que fiz aqui que contém um Token que gerei no Facebook Developer.

Comment: Ah entendi. Achei que fosse algo a ver com o Token do Facebook. Beleza!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que era.

É que o Facebook usa a sessão nativa do PHP internalmente para salvar dois dados vindos da url, que é o `state` e o `code`. Mas o `Laravel`, que é o framework que uso, não usa a sessão nativa do PHP.

Me recusei a dar um `session_start` só por conta dessa biblioteca.

Criei uma adaptação para a biblioteca, para usar a sessão do laravel.

http://github.com/wallacemaxters/facebook

Agora está funcionando, como esperado!

Exemplo:

```
$api_data = Config::get('facebook_api');

$facebook = new Facebook([
    'app_id'                  => $api_data['app_id'],
    'app_secret'              => $api_data['app_secret'],
    'persistent_data_handler' => new Laravel3SessionPersistentData,
]);
```